# ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined in react-bootstrap-select

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-bootstrap

Seems like react-bootstrap-select needs jQuery. But in the GitHub usage section they mentioned to require only these three.

https://github.com/tjwebb/react-bootstrap-select

```
React = require('react');
React.Bootstrap = require('react-bootstrap');
React.Bootstrap.Select = require('react-bootstrap-select');
```

I am not using `jQuery` in my `react` project. Is there any alternative of `react-bootstrap-select` without `jQuery`.

There are some other `react` library available for select but they don't have a separate search box under drop down like `react-bootstrap-select` has. Attached is the image of how I want my select box.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Please see my update in my answer. Maybe this helps you, too.

Answer (score 2):

I've got `jQuery` added via this code:

```
const jQuery = require('jquery');
window.jQuery = jQuery;
React.Bootstrap = require('react-bootstrap');
React.Bootstrap.Select = require('react-bootstrap-select');
```

Then the error

> jQuery is not defined

is gone.

**But**

it still does not work for me, because `react-bootstrap-select` is still using `React.createClass` which was removed in reactjs 16. 
So I still got the error

> TypeError: React.createClass is not a function

I'm facing now, to use a different library than `react-bootstrap-select`. Hope this helps a little bit.

**UPDATE**

I've got it working now with package `bootstrap-select` instead of `react-bootstrap-select`. It works with the following imports:

```
const jQuery = require('jquery');
window.jQuery = jQuery;
import ('bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css');
require('bootstrap-select');
```

Then you can use

```
componentDidMount() {
    jQuery('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
}
```

or

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    jQuery('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
}
```

and / or with `bootstrap-select` options

```
componentDidMount() {
     jQuery('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
         liveSearch:true,
         selectOnTab: true,
     });
}
```

I don't know if it is the best way, but it is working.

Comment: it is the best way if it's working. because i tried a lot with react-bootstrap-select but wasted a day.